# How can I support gles1.1 extensions feature OES using gles 2.x?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, porting, opengl-es-1.1

Is there anyway to support gles1.1 OES extensions using gles 2.x or 3.x? This is the snippet of my code

```
bool ColorBuffer::bind_fbo()
{
    if (m_fbo) {
        // fbo already exist - just bind
        s_gl.glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, m_fbo);
        return true;
    }

    s_gl.glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &m_fbo);
    s_gl.glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, m_fbo);
    s_gl.glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,
                               GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES,
                               GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex, 0);
    GLenum status = s_gl.glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES);
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
        s_gl.glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, 0);
        s_gl.glDeleteFramebuffersOES(1, &m_fbo);
        m_fbo = 0;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I need to re-implement this code using gles 2.x or higher since new platform doesn't support gles 1.1 anymore.

Anyone know how to do?

Thanks,
Jiancong

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no way to use it in ES 2.0 or 3.0 However, it seems to work if you remove suffixes, OES. Try it.

Comment: Yes, works. Thank you!.